# Difference between Jax-ws RI and metro

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I'm not sure of my understanding here, it is stated that JAX-WS reference implementation provides metro core to glassfish. However, I've downloaded the latest source of JAX-WS RI and it has nothing to do with the latest Metro source.

I need a functionality that I found in Metro source code (UnsetSecurityMUValue) so I thought I should find it in the latest JAX-WS RI implementation, but it is not... So is it actually some kind of fork? Are the two mutually exclusive?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Metro 2.1.1](http://metro.java.net/2.1.1/) release consists of following components:

- Metro/WSIT 2.1.1
- JAX-WS RI 2.2.5
- JAXB RI 2.2.4-1

UnsetSecurityMUValue functionality belongs to WS-security support that belongs to [WSIT](http://wsit.java.net/).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to use an up to date WSIT with the older version of Metro?

When I update it as a whole, my apps break for unknown reasons (WebServiceException: null is not a valid service when injecting the @webserviceref).

Comment: I think such libs compatibility needs testing anyway. You have to try to know for sure if it fits in your case. Also you can post new question on SO about that "null is not a valid service".